# What is the earliest that a Tier 2 (General) Visa to the UK can be applied for?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, working-visas

My company is sponsoring my Tier 2 visa to the UK. They are saying that the visa application cannot be submitted earlier than 45 days from the intended date of travel. Although, this website says that the visa can be applied upto 3 months before the intended date of travel: https://www.gov.uk/tier-2-general

> **How long it will take**
>
> You can apply for a visa up to 3 months before the date you travel to the UK.

Does anyone know what the generally recommended duration is?

Answer (score 1):

I would say apply as early as possible, up to 3 months before the intended date of travel (https://www.gov.uk/tier-2-general). It could take some time to process your visa, depending on where and what time of year you apply. Please try to clarify the application date with your company.

Some important things to think about:

- What are the approx. visa processing times for your country?
- Does it give you enough time to make arrangements to travel / relocate to the UK? (It's strongly recommended that you make travel arrangements *after* you receive your visa.)
- Can you make it in time for your job start date?
- On the chance that your visa is delayed or refused, will you have time to make a fresh application?